# replace array values from YML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, replace, helper

I have a YML file with a list of emails and I am trying to do some corrections on a helper file but I cant seem to update and keep that updated info

I need to change the the email base on the environment sent on the config files. 
my biggest problem is that the info updated is not being saved on the `file_data` array

in all environments other than productions I want all emails to got a **dev-email address**  but in production I can do a `eval()` to load the email from the config file

Example YML file

```
#config/brands_mailer.yml
brand1:
  support: 'Appname::Application.config.support_email'
  sales: 'Appname::Application.config.email'
  accounting: 'Appname::Application.config.accounting_email'
brand2:
  support: 'Appname::Application.config.barnd2_support_email'
  sales: 'Appname::Application.config.barnd2_email'
  accounting: 'Appname::Application.config.barnd2_accounting_email'
brand3:
  support: 'Appname::Application.config.barnd3_support_email'
  sales: 'Appname::Application.config.barnd3_email'
  accounting: 'Appname::Application.config.barnd3_accounting_email'
```

now I have a mail-helper that looks like

```
# app/helpers/mailers/mailr_helper.rb

module Mailers
  module MailrHelper
    def get_brand_emails(options ={})
      file_data = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config','brands_mailer.yml'))[options[:brand].to_s]
      file_data.each do |fd|
        unless Rails.env.production? 
          fd[1] << 'moo@aol.com' # This appends to the current value 
          fd[1] = fd[1].gsub(fd[1], 'new@aol.com') # this changes the data but it does not persist 
         else
          fd[1] << eval(fd[1])  
         end
      end
      file_data
    end    
end
```

Comment: Can you add some more information about what you are trying to do, and what, if anything, the specific problem is?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I updated the question with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with. I still would like to refactor and make it cleaner

## app/helpers/mailers/mailr_helper.rb

```
module Mailers
  module MailrHelper
    def get_brand_emails(options ={})
      file_data = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config','brands_mailer.yml'))[options[:brand].to_s]
      file_data.each do |fd|
        unless Rails.env.production? 
          file_data['customer_support'] = "dev@email.com"
          file_data['new_pro']          = "dev@email.com"
          file_data['new_user']          = "dev@email.com"
         else
          file_data['customer_support'] = eval(file_data['customer_support'])
          file_data['new_pro']          = eval(file_data['new_pro'])
          file_data['new_user']         = eval(file_data['new_user'])
         end
      end
      file_data
    end    
end
```

this way I can still force all the email to go to one place and only forward emails in production

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend that you use a mail interceptor in your rails configuration files for non-production environments. With that in place you'll be able to use and test the same mail process in all environment without having to worry about generating email to live recipients. [Here](https://abigbang.wordpress.com/2013/05/23/send-it-hence/) I've described how I tend to set up mail interceptor for my apps.

Comment: thanks, but we are using mail-catcher in development but we still have to be able to change those values for when we are testing the actually emails across multiple platforms like g-mail, yahoo, Hotmail, phones, and others. Plus I don't really want to send the emails to the sales people from the company from a staging server .

Comment: I think that the problem @MZaragoza is getting is that he cant seem to update the value of the key value array. the business decision to user  *** mail interceptor*** or something else is not really relevant.

Comment: @AldoDelgado, yes that is now obvious from the responses MZaragoza has made, but it wasn't when I posted my "solution".

Comment: @ReggieB I still want to say thanks for posting and helping out